# Symfony - Service in Twig template

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I made my website with Symfony 3.4 and I developed my own User management bundle. More specifically the bundle contains 2 entities: User and Group. Below are the ManyToMany relationship between it and some getters/setters:

```
<?php
class User
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group")
    */
    private $groups;

    public function addGroup(Group $group)
    {
                   //
    }

    public function removeGroup(Group $group)
    {
                   //
    }

    public function getGroup()
    {
                   //
    }
```

and

```
<?php
class Group
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
    */
    private $users;
```

Very simple. Everything works well, for examples:

- User "carlos" gets group #1 and group #2
- User "peter" gets group #3

What I can't do is to display a specific text **in my twig template** to all the users of a specific group.
What I tried:

- 1. Creating a new service in my bundle, then retrieve the current user. DONE.
- 2. Get the list of the current user's groups. I'M STUCK HERE.
- 3. Inject the service in twig and then use a {%if}{%endif} statement. DONE (TESTED).

Below my custom Service:

```
<?php

namespace CoreBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class AuthorizationChecker
{

    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
                               $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
    *
    * Get current user's groups
    * @return array
    *
    */

    public function getUserGroups()
    {
                   $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
                   // I can var_dump($user) in Twig
                   // But don't know how to get his group(s).
    }

}
```

I managed to get the current user but I don't know how to get the groups he belongs to.
Any idea ? Is there a better way to achieve all of this ?

Comment: sorry but is not too clear where is the problem: the `getGroup` method of the `User` object doesn't work?

Comment: There's more than one way to do it. I guess easiest is to add a `hasGroup()` method to your entity using the `get($key)` method from `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`. So, in your template you can use something like `{% if (user.hasGroup(2)) %}`.
Groups can be loaded along with you User Entity, but almost all codes are _lazy load_. So you need to do a `$user->getGroups()` before check if a $user has a Group.

Comment: You can make your service a global variable in your config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the logged in user data directly in the twig template without requesting anything in the controller. The user is accessible like this : `app.user`.

I would add a method `hasGroup` to your `User` object then you can call that method in your twig template to test if a user belongs to a group.

If you did this then you can just do this:

```
{% if app.user.hasGroup('groupName') %} 
     //do something 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Perfect ! I added a hasGroup() and getGroupNames() in my UserEnity, then I'm now able to use your code. Cool ! Much more easier than my original idea.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can get what groups have the user. What I know for sure is that you can use the `{% if is_granted('ROLE_WHATEVER') %}` inside twig.

So a group is a collection of roles... Perhaps you can check straigth the roles... Hopefully will be usefull for you. Sorry if it doesn't help.

Comment: No I have to use my GroupEntity, not the roles. Many thanks anyway!

Comment: The ChipDean answer looks nice :)

Answer (score -1):

If user may have several groups and the same group may belong to many users - it's a classic ManyToMany Relation.

1. I see *two* ManyTo**One**. If it is not a typo with this annotations
   you'll get `group_id` in your `users` table **AND** `user_id` in
   your `groups` table which ist not a many-to-many model. Take a look
   at this http://ormcheatsheet.com/#manytomany and especialy this => https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3121916
2. Check what `$user->getGroup()` returns. If it returns a group (single object of `Group`) and not an `ArrayCollection` -> the relation does not work as you described and you wan't get a list of assigned groups.
3. Always check your relations with `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

P.S. If you run `bin/console doctrine:generate:entity YourBundleName:Group` you'll get an error

> "Group" is a reserved word

So I assume you've created all entities manually. Double check if there's a typo or bad copy/paste